# agreements are empty with germansetup in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

From my `/checkout/onepage/` there is a popup window for the AGB:  `/germansetup/frontend/agreements/id/1/`

Problem is that this page does not show any text. Just a background image from the template.

The popup is defined in `germansetup.xml`:

```
<germansetup_frontend_agreements>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/popup.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/text" name="agreement" />
    </reference>
</germansetup_frontend_agreements>
```

I don't know what block he is trying to load here but I would like him to show my static block `mrg_business_terms`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to have changed at some point. For me (using Magento 1.9.2.4), what worked was adding 'cms/block' to the list of whitelisted blocks.

Comment: Nice. Where can you add something to the list of whitelisted blocks?

Comment: It's under System -> Permissions -> Blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Sales > Terms and Conditions (German: Verkäufe > Bestellbedingungen).

Here you see the list of checkout agreements. In my case I needed to change the content block id:

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="mrg_business_terms"}}
```